# Deriving the fundamental solution to heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, differential, heat-equation, fundamental-solution

We are seeking a general solution to the heat equation in the form
$$u(t,x)=t^{-\alpha}v\left(\frac{\|x\|^2}{t}\right), x \in \mathbb{R}^n,\alpha>0,t>0$$
for an appropriate function $v:(0,+\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}.$

1. Plug into $u(t,x)$ into the heat equation and rearrange it so that it depends only on $\frac{\|x\|^2}{t}$.
2. Substitute $\frac{\|x\|^2}{t}$ with new variable $s$ and multiply the new equation with the integration factor of $s^{\beta}$, choose $\alpha,\beta$ so that the new equation is an equation of derivatives.

I have calculated the derivatives using chain rule for $v(f(t,x)),\;f(t,x)=\frac{\|x\|^2}{t}$
$$u_t(t,x)=-\alpha t^{-1-\alpha}v\left(\frac{\|x\|^2}{t}\right)-t^{-\alpha - 2}v_t\left(\frac{\|x\|^2}{t}\right)$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}=t^{-\alpha}\frac{\partial v}{\partial f}(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x})=t^{-\alpha}\frac{2x_i}{t}\frac{\partial v}{\partial f}$$
$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_i^2}(t,x)=2t^{-\alpha-1}\frac{\partial v}{\partial f} +4t^{-\alpha-2}x_i^2\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x_i^2}\left(\frac{\|x\|^2}{t}\right),$$
which yields
$$\triangle_x u=t^{-\alpha}\sum_{i=1}^n(\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial^2 f}\frac{4x_i^2}{t^2}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial f}\frac{2}{t})=2nt^{-\alpha-1}\frac{\partial v}{\partial v}+t^{-\alpha-2}4\|x\|^2\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial^2 f}.$$

Plugging into the heat equation yields

$$u_t-\Delta u= -\alpha t^{-\alpha-1}v-t^{-\alpha-2}\frac{\partial v}{\partial f}-2nt^{-\alpha-1}\frac{\partial v}{\partial f}-4t^{-\alpha-2}\|x\|^2\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial^2 f}=0.$$

We multiply by $t^{-\alpha-1}$
$$-\alpha v-\frac{\|x\|^2}{t}\frac{\partial v}{\partial f}-2n\frac{\partial v}{\partial f}-4\frac{\|x\|^2}{t}\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial^2 f}=0,$$
satisfying 1).Substituting $s=\frac{\|x\|^2}{t}$ and multiplying the equation by integral factor $s^{\beta}$ yields
$$-\alpha s^{\beta}v-s^{\beta+1}\frac{\partial v}{\partial s}-s^{\beta}2n\frac{\partial v}{\partial s}-4s^{\beta+1}\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial^2 s}=0$$
I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: Are you sure about $v_{x_i x_i}$? Seems that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\|x\|^2 = 2x_i$

Comment: Use spatial spherical coordinates to begin with.

Comment: I added the calculation for the first derivate x_i of u to clarify my approach

Comment: $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_i}$ doesn't have a meaning since $v$ is a function of one variable only.

Comment: In particular, when you differentiate $v(\frac{\|x\|^2}{t})$, you need to use the chain rule, keeping in mind that $v$ is a function of one variable only.

Comment: @Deane thank you for your tip, using the chain rule as in the edited post, I have managed to get the desired form of the equation. However, I don't know how to choose parameters so that only the derivatives remain.

Comment: You really shouldn’t write partial derivatives of $v$ since it is a function of one variable. In particular, given a function $g(t,x)$, it follows by the chain rule that $$\partial_t(v(g(t,x)) = v’(g(t,x))\partial_tg(t,x). $$ A similar formula holds for the partial derivative with respect to each $x^i$.